# Can´t open an internal page in Cypress Chrome

Tags: cypress

We have an cypress issue that is similar to the issue described in "https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/850". The reason for why I am creating a new post is that I have done some changes in the environment which makes this work but only after the first fail and then manually click on the failing URL.

Test1:

1. Default `cypress\plugins\index.js` file (no changes)
2. lauch the internal page `cy.visit('xxx')`
3. Error 401.
4. Click on the link below the error text. Another tab is opened and message UNAUTHORIZED is shown.
5. Paste same URL in default Chrome->works fine.

Test2:

1. Modify the `cypress\plugins\index.js`: `args.push('--proxy-pac-url=xxx')`  (I have tested other arguments but this is the only one that makes something different)
2. Lauch the internal page `cy.visit('xxx')`
3. Error 403.
4. Click on the link below the error text. Another tab is opened and the page is shown CORRECTLY.

This is the reason why I post this new message. I want to ask if there is a way to get Cypress to open the page automatically via `cy.visit()` in the same way as when I click on the failing URL and it opens the page in the same cypress browser but just another tab?

Comment: Additional info:
In TEST1 if I check the network traffic (F12) I don´t see anywhere the GET request to our internal page. This is inline with what developers say, i.e. that they don´t see a call from us at all when running via Cypress Chrome. So the Request URL is "http://localhost:60901/cypress/tests..."

The Request URL however in TEST2 (when it works in same Cypress Chrome browser but another tab) is "https://dap-ii...", i.e. the internal page.

Why is Cypress not executing this real request??

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?.. am stuck on similar lines